# keeping track of sql selected row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, multithreading

I'm trying to create an application that have two threads running concurrently, one streaming data and added to sql table with java and another thread will read row from the same table and process that data it read. My program will stream endlessly until the user choose to stop.

The problem is my second thread that process the data only process certain amount of data that added to the table before the thread is active then the thread just rest and only streaming thread stream the data the whole time while it doesn't come up to process the new data inserted.

How can I keep track of the data selected and keep the thread alive to process the new data that added?

Comment: Why use a sql table to stream data from A to B and not a direct network connection between A and B?